# How to display red borders on required or invalid value input element in Chrome just like Firefox behaviour for HTML5 validation?

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, firefox

I have to bring red borders around the input element in chrome on HTML5 validation like as that of Firefox.

[image: Firefox Validation]

I have search it a lot but unable to find precise answer.
Any help of how to do it using css is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You use the `:valid` pseudo class.

To shamelessly copy the code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:valid:

```css
input:invalid {
  background-color: #ffdddd;
}
form:invalid {
  border: 5px solid #ffdddd;
}
input:valid {
  background-color: #ddffdd;
}
form:valid {
  border: 5px solid #ddffdd;
}
input:required {
  border-color: #800000;
  border-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>Enter a URL:</label>
  <input type="url" />
  <br />
  <br />
  <label>Enter an email address:</label>
  <input type="email" required/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding 'required' in the DOM element

```
<input name="heading" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="heading" maxlength="35" required />
```